# Passing text from textarea with AJAX to PHP page?

Tags: php, ajax

I'm going to use a time interval to call function autoSave(). Inside the function I'm going to use AJAX to send the content what has been written inside the forms textarea. Hmmm, how do I get a variable or something that holds the text from the form to send with AJAX to a PHP page?

In the PHP page I'm going to use code like this to get te content of the textarea

```
$articleText = isset($_POST['articleText']) ? $_POST['articleText'] : '';
```

But I need some help to pass the text from the form togehter with som info like ?p=add-reply'

I guess the AJAX would look like something like this, but I'm not sure about the variables?

```
$.ajax({
url: "PStoreForm.php", 
type: "POST",
dataType: "text",
data: ??????????????
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
$.ajax({
    url: "PStoreForm.php?param=xxxx&param2=yyy", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data: "articleText="+$("#yourtextareaid").val()
    });
```

Comment: Must the script in between <form></form> or could it be somewhere else and still work?

Comment: Anywhere you want, as long as it is called in a page containing an element with that id. Actually, in general it's better to have it elsewhere (say in a separate js file) to separate HTML from JS.

Comment: OK, but if I also want to add text from a input field, do I add that to the last row after a comma? Like this: data: "articleText=".$("#yourtextareaid").val(), "articleTitle=".$("title").val() ??

Comment: @3Dkreativ: No, just pass it as a normal query string. `"articleText="+$("#textareaid").val()+"&title="+$("#titleid").val()`
PS: I mistyped the command... it needs a `+` not a `.`! Corrected in the answer

Comment: Help! This isn't working! What am I doing wrong? I'm calling this page to save the values in DB, but nothing happens!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: can you be a tad more specific? Start checking with Firebug if the AJAX call goes through, and check its return value.

Comment: Hi again! Firebug says after some time; Fel: uncaught exception: [Exception... "prompt aborted by user"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/components/nsPrompter.js :: openTabPrompt :: line 468"  data: no]

Comment: Sorrry that was a message from the error console of Firefox. How do I check with Firebug?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: open the Firebug console tab, reload the page and you should see a line adding up for each AJAX call. If you click on the line for your call you should see if there is any error message.

Comment: I discovered a new function in Firebug, I clicked on on Net and then XHR and status says 404 Not Found ?? Hmmm ??

Comment: @3D-kreativ: ok... is the path to the PHP correct? Is the PHP file actually there? Are the permissions correct (755 should do)?

Comment: url: "PAddReplyProcess.php?replyArticleId={$id}", The last part is PHP code that I paste. I run it on localhost. The calling page is in same place as the called one. Permission, the file is working as always when I use in other ways

Comment: You can't use `$id`, in a JS call... `$id` is a PHP variable. You should pass the id to the JS function where the `$.ajax` call is done and then append it to the URL using `+`

Comment: But when the page is processed on the server there will be a number in the javascript code. This is how it look when I right click on the page  url: "PAddReplyProcess.php?replyArticleId=1",

Comment: Any ideas what could be wrong? Sorry but I have to close and go to bed, must up early tomorrow. Perhaps we could try to solve this tomorrow eavning?

Comment: @3D-kreativ: `$id` will not be changed unless you write it as `<? echo $id;?>` (which is kind of ugly as you're mixing JS and PHP, but should work). Otherwise have the ID stored in an hidden field and pull it up directly with JS.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it will change since all JS code is inside a PHP variable otherwise it shouldn't be: "PAddReplyProcess.php?replyArticleId=1" in the web pages code? Or? Am I wrong? There must be something else that is wrong!? Why is it ugly to mix PHP and JS? How do I pull up the ID from a hidden field with JS?

Comment: It's ugly because it makes it more difficult to maintain. Try googling for *unobtrusive code*. Remember that JS is processed on the client, not on the server, so once the PHP spits out the page, the server has not got any more control on the page. To read a value from an hidden field just use `$("#IDofTheField").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//...
data: document.getElementsByTagName("textarea") [0].value
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$.post("PStoreForm.php", {articleText: $('#textarea').val()}, function(){alert("saved");} );
```